# macro for switching between auto_ptr and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, unique-ptr

In a project that still uses pre-C++11 I wanted to prepare the source for the switch by compiling with a C++11 compiler and fixing the errors. They consisted of

- instances of `std::auto_ptr<T>` replaced with `std::unique_ptr<T>`
- where necessary, wrapped the smart pointer with `std::move()`
- some `0` and `NULL` replaced with `nullptr`

Now I want to switch back to a pre-C++ compiler and write a macro that can switch back the changes, so that, when the time for the final compiler switch is there, I simply remove the macro. I tried

```
#ifndef HAVE_CXX11
#define nullptr NULL
namespace std {
#define unique_ptr<exvector> auto_ptr<exvector>
}
#endif
```

(with `exvector` an example type used with the smart pointer) This and similar attempts don't work because macros can't change template types. I also used `typedef` with no better results.

Is this possible at all and, if so, how?

Comment: First, the preprocessor has no notion of namespaces, or any kind of language construct except maybe the () operator.
Now, I don't know about macro. Can't you use your IDE's refactor tool once your upgrade? And if that doesn't work, you can always write a tool that uses Clang's AST and analyze where the changes are needed to generate new source code from the old source code

Comment: Clang Modernize might also be of interest, specifically replace auto-ptr: http://clang.llvm.org/extra/ReplaceAutoPtrTransform.html

Comment: Honestly? You are just asking for troubles. This is the kind of things that macros can do but should never be used for. Instead, just branch; use your Version Control System (mercurial? git?) to go back to the version prior the introduction of C++11 features, and maintain the two branches for a while. It'll be a bit painful, but will not expose you to weird random bugs...

Comment: I might actually do that. However the question stands, and is probably interesting for others.

Comment: Just curious... what compiler?

Comment: Also branching will allow you to take full advantage of the many advances of C++11. Maintaining both in parallel will just inhibit progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just `nullptr` and `unique_ptr`, this could work:

```
#ifndef HAVE_CXX11
  #define nullptr NULL
  #define unique_ptr auto_ptr
#endif
```

But I don't know how you plan to cope with the different semantics of `unique_ptr` and `auto_ptr`.

If you're willing to live with some undefined behaviour for a while (of the kind unlikely to cause actual issues), you could also provide your own `std::move`:

```
namespace std {

template <class T>
T& move(T &x) { return x; }

}
```

It's UB, because you're not allowed to add anything to `namespace std`. But if it's only a temporary measure, it should be safe (the pre-11 compiler is unlikely to have the name `std::move`).

Comment: If you replace classT with class T I will accept your answer because it compiles nicely! 8)

Comment: This move will not work with temporaries, though, only with named variables.

Comment: @MatthieuM. True indeed, but how often does normal code call `std::move` on temporary `unique_ptr` objects? I understand this is supposed to be a temporary, transition measure.

Comment: @Angew: I understand the need for pragmatism and all, but honestly I just feel like the OP would be better serve by swallowing the pill instead of piling up hacks upon hacks. `move` should mostly work, `unique_ptr` should mostly work (unless it's stored in a container, of course, there is a reason `auto_ptr` is deprecated), ... but it's the "should" I worry about. Aren't we supposed to promote best practices so that the future readers (and not just the OP) can rely on our advices?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I think the move function here is fine.  It fails with temporaries sure, but I see that as a good thing: it should not be used with temporaries.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, at least it's a compile-time failure, whereas using this `unique_ptr` within a container would compile but cause run-time failures.

Answer (score 4):

I would introduce very explicit macros like

```
//Defines to overcome pre C++11 limitations regarding 
//std::auto_ptr and absence of 'good' move (i.e. std::move) semantics.
//Strictly post C++11 code should use std::unique_ptr and std::move explicitly.
//All other code should use the macros.
//If pre-C++11 ceases to be a target the macros may be replaced...
#ifdef HAVE_CXX11 //Or whatever...

#define UNIQUE_PTR_TYPE std::unique_ptr
#define MOVE_UNIQUE_PTR(PTR) std::move(PTR)

#else

#define UNIQUE_PTR_TYPE std::auto_ptr
#define MOVE_UNIQUE_PTR(PTR) (PTR)

#endif
```

Why? Because even a casual reader will see that some substitution is going on.

Yes the code will look ugly but a safe "not going to blow anyone's fingers off ugly". We're engineers not poets and that's our kind of beautiful!

However I have to say that I agree with the poster who thinks you should branch the code. This is not the only incompatibility and your code will become increasingly bloated and you might find you're doing more work (and introducing more errors) trying to make a single branch multi-target than branching.

Macros are wonderful things but anything of the form:

```
#define <common symbol> <something else>
```

needs to be 100% guaranteed benign "you don't need to know it was substituted" before it can be condoned.

I just don't think:

```
#define unique_ptr auto_ptr
```

Or anything else that makes this substitution invisible quite passes that test.
`unique_ptr` and `auto_ptr` aren't the same and the whole point that `auto_ptr` is deprecated is because you need to be careful with it.

For the lulz (to bed in my point about invisible substitutes) try:

```
#define if(A) if(((A)&&rand()>128)||rand()>(RAND_MAX-128))
```

That should keep the feckers busy for the afternoon...
The best bit is you haven't seeded with `srand()` the failures will be repeatable!

Comment: This seems to be better than just adding the comment `@todo replace with unique_ptr` to each use of `std::auto_ptr` (with unique-ptr semantics) in pre-C++11 code, because it's more specific for search&replace sessions. And yes, I see that it's better to resist the (big) temptation to make pre-C++11 code looking more clean than it is.

Comment: ... on the other hand, this is quite pointless because `auto_ptr` itself is such a specific todo marker, and [it's *deprecated* which means *still supported* in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893795/2932052)

Comment: `auto_ptr` is supported in C++11 though is removed from C++17. Though I assume the OP was trying to make sure the code can be upgraded to the preferred C++11 constructs.

Comment: @wolf forgot to tag you.

Comment: Ah good point, so it's (in my POV) even better to use `auto_ptr` between C++98 and C++11 code, and replace it when switching to C++17. Your suggestion of course works, but I see the also a problem in documentation and correlated changes: you need to include the defines from somewhere, and you need to replace also include directives some day; this means two changes where only one would be sufficient in the `#include <memory>`+`std::auto_ptr` combination.

Comment: @Wolf I do tend to agree. Code that uses pre-C++11 using `auto_ptr` works after. Though where replaced with `std::unique_ptr` failures to compile are opportunities to review logic validity. But aside from that wait until your target is C++17 and try to avoid having targets <C++11 and C++17. That much separation sounds nasrsty.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
#ifdef NOT_HAVING_CPP_11 
namespace std{
template<typename T>
struct unique_ptr : public auto_ptr<T>{}; }
#endif
```

This way, after you have replaced all your instances of auto_ptr on your old code with unique_ptr you can remove the NOT_HAVING_CPP_11 macro and will compile without warning on a modern compiler.

Comment: Nice, better than macro tricks. But you should at least mention this will require duplicating all the constructors.

Comment: @Angew Not if your compiler implements inheriting constructors

Comment: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
     struct unique_ptr : public auto_ptr<T>{}; }
                                    ^
    compiler.h:16:36: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token

Comment: @KABoissonneault: inheriting constructors are opt-in, you still have to ask for them.

Comment: Introducing new symbols in `std` is forbidden. The only authorized thing is to specialize existing templates.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Inheriting ctors is a C++11 feature. The OP wants a solution for their pre-C++11 compiler.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Forbidden as in "UB, but as a temporary workaround, this case is likely safe."

Comment: @rwst Looks like you didn't include the header for `auto_ptr`.

Comment: @Angew: I don't like betting on UB, it's a wild beast.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if no_Cxx11
  template<class T>
  struct up:auto_ptr<T> {
    up(T* t):auto_ptr(t) {}
    up(auto_ptr& o):auto_ptr(o) {}
  };
  T& my_move(T& t){return t;}
  struct my_nullptr_t {
    template<class T>
    operator T*()const{return NULL;}
    // template operator T* isn't always looked for:
    operator void*()const{return NULL;}
  };
  static const my_nullptr_t nullptr;
#else
  template<class T>
  using up=std::unique_ptr<T>;
  template<class T>
  decltype(std::move(std::declval<T>()))
  my_move(T&& t) {
    return std::move(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
  using my_nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t;
#endif
```

This requires replacing `std::unique_ptr` with `up`, and `std::nullptr_t` with `my_nullptr_t` and `std::move` with `my_move` in your code base.  In C++11, they are all C++11.  In C++03, they are emulated.

You can even go a step further, and teach `my_move` to return a `lvalue_up`, and make `up` refuse to copy from `up` in C++03 mode (manual move semantics).  You can even set up auto-swapping on containers when you move from them in C++03.

Comment: What's the upside of using `up` instead of `my_unique_ptr`?

Comment: @wolf I don't see where I claimed there was such an upside?

Comment: ... I just found it confusing to introduce such a short template name, so I saw an obvious *down*side using `up`, and the pun was too tempting ;)