# C++ std:.auto_ptr or std::unique_ptr (to support multiple compilers, even old C++03 compilers)?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, c++03

I'm trying to update some C++ code, I'd like to move toward a more modern code (c++11), but I still need to compile the code with some older compilers (c++03 compliant), because of supported platform constraints.

I know in C++11 compilers std::auto_ptr is deprecated, but because of the older compiler support, I can't just replace them with std::unique_ptr.

Is there a good practice to handle this "old compiler support, but start to move to C++11"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noted, std::auto_ptr<> has been deprecated in C++11
([Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/)).

Moving to c++11 std::unique_ptr<> is the right way, as also stated by Herb Sutter in
[GotW89](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/):

> 4. What’s the deal with auto_ptr?
>    auto_ptr is most charitably characterized as a valiant attempt to create a unique_ptr before C++ had move semantics. auto_ptr is now deprecated, and should not be used in new code.
>    If you have auto_ptr in an existing code base, when you get a chance try doing a global search-and-replace of auto_ptr to unique_ptr; the vast majority of uses will work the same, and it might expose (as a compile-time error) or fix (silently) a bug or two you didn’t know you had.

Please also note that C++17 is going to remove std::auto_ptr.

I think there may be different ways of solving your problem, the "right" one also depends on how your actual code is written.
A few options are:

## Option 1

Use boost::unique_ptr

## Option 2

Conditionally use auto_ptr or unique_ptr based on __cplusplus.

> class Myclass {
> #if __cplusplus < 201103L
> std::auto_ptr m_ptr;
> #else
> std::unique_ptr m_ptr;
> #endif
> ...

This will be scattered in every place where you reference auto_ptr, I don't really like it.
May be look less awkward if all your references to std::auto_ptr are already typedef'ed (just conditionally change the typedef).

## Option 3

Conditionally use using and aliasing to "define" auto_ptr (and reference it without std:: namespace).

> #if __cplusplus < 201103L
> using std::auto_ptr;
> #else
> template 
> using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr;
> #endif

Drawback: you keep using "auto_ptr", but in c++11 it means std::unique_ptr.
Really confusing...

## Option 3.1

Probably slightly better than option 3:
reverse using aliases and prefer unique_ptr name.

## Option 4

Wrap the std:: smart pointer (conditionally auto_ptr or unique_ptr) in your own defined template smart pointer class.
This may be cumbersome and requires search and replacement of all auto_ptr references with your new class.

## Other dirty options

Other options involve definitions inside the std:: namespace, which I think is prohibited by the standard,
or using preprocessor #define to ...ehm... "rename" unique_ptr to auto_ptr just for old C++03 compilers.

Comment: Great and complete answer. Boost is tempting, but I also have constraints to (try to) avoid it. Please don't ask, constraints are not defined by me :-(.

Comment: @roalz: "*C++17 may definitely remove std::auto_ptr*" It "may" not do anything. `auto_ptr` *is* being removed from C++17. While yes, it's possible for the committee to decide not to do so, it's highly unlikely at this point that they will.

Comment: I believe code breaks if you start with valid `auto_ptr` code and replace it with `unique_ptr`, and vice versa.

Comment: Are the constraints specific to Boost, or encompassing to all "third party libraries"? I wrote a [backports library for C++03 (and others)](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/wiki?name=Features) which includes `unique_ptr`, and in case you can't just grab the library, the documentation mentions Howard Hinnart's early implementation that you can use as a basis. Doesn't get you *everything* in C++03 mode (by definition, it can't), but it should get you up to usable and upwards.

Comment: With MSVC (and clang-cl) adding  '-D_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=1' to your CFLAGS works too.

Comment: C++ tooling has evolved since my answer.
Yes, MSVC now provides _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC and others, see documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170

Comment: I think OP means boost::scoped_ptr.

Answer (score 3):

In this exact case you can start modernizing your code by using `boost::unique_ptr` instead of `auto_ptr`, which is not recommended.

Overall, big part of C++11 libraries is straight-up taken from boost, so it will be good place to start.

Comment: Unfortunately I also have constraints to (try) not use Boost (sorry, no decision power on them!)

Answer (score 2):

If I was serious, I'd create a `notstd` namespace.

The goal would be that in C++11, `notstd` consists of a series of aliases to `std` types.  In C++03, it has pseudo-C++11 code.

The C++03 `notstd` code would not be 100% compatible with C++11 `std`, but rather valid C++03 `notstd` would in turn produce valid C++11 behavior.

For example, I might use special tagged "reference-wrapper" like types for `notstd::move` references instead of rvalue references, and have my move-only types require such tagged "reference-wrapper"s.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<class U>
  struct moved_t {
    U& u;
    // relies on NRVO, which is pretty universally supported.
    // also relies in U being default-constructible:
    operator U()const{ U tmp; std::swap(u, tmp); return tmp; }
  };
  template<class U>
  moved_t<U> move(U& u) { return {u}; }
  template<class T>
  struct unique_ptr {
    unique_ptr( moved_t<unique_ptr<T>> > ); // move ctor
    template<class U>
    unique_ptr( moved_t<unique_ptr<U>> > ); // move ctor
  private:
    unique_ptr(unique_ptr const&);
  };
}
```

So your code would use `notstd::unique_ptr<T>`.  There would be no implicit rvalue conversion, so every spot where you move a `notstd::unique_ptr<T>` you'd have to `notstd::move` it.

Sadly this means `notstd::unique_ptr<T>` cannot be put into `std` containers.  Some hack may have to be done to get that to work (neither can `auto_ptr` safely).

This is a non-trivial task.  `boost::unique_ptr` was an attempt to generate unique_ptr like semantics in C++03, and they are going to do a better job than you will most likely.  If you cannot use them directly, read up on what they did and reimplement it yourself.